# Retrieving value including input mask from TextBox field - Access VBA 2016

Tags: ms-access, vba, masking

I have an input mask of `JAAA-AAA` on a `TextBox`, so when the user enters that input field, they will see this: "J___-___".

However, when they fill it out like so, J123-321, and I get the value using `[myfield].Value`, it says that the value is only 123321. It strips the preset 'J' and '-' I had in there. How can I prevent the stripping of these characters when I retrieve the value from this field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the second part of the input mask property to `0`.

If you look at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/textbox-inputmask-property-access), you can see it has 3 parts, and the 2nd part controls if the mask is stored with the data, or only the data is stored.

The final mask property would be the following:

```
\JAAA\-AAA;0;_
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. The one thing is that Access automatically adds a '\' before the 'J' and the '-', so it looks like this `\JAAA\-AAA;0;_` if you wanted to edit your answer to include this